# Will Direct 2D be better than Qt at rendering lines onto a off screen buffer

Tags: c#, c++, qt, graphics2d, direct2d

I have a data visualization application (Parallel Coordinates). This involves drawing loads of lines on screen. The application is for huge datasets. The test data set involves ~ 2.5M lines (2527700 exact). The screen is going to be cluttered but it shows some pattern. The application has facility to scale along X and Y. At typical zoom levels it draws around 300K lines. The application is written in Qt and the time taken to render is respectable. Typical numbers are (time in ms)

Time taken:  496
Drew  1003226 lines

Time taken:  603
Drew  1210032 lines

Time taken:  112
Drew  344582 lines

Time taken:  182
Drew  387960 lines

Time taken:  178
Drew  361424 lines

Time taken:  222
Drew  676470 lines

Time taken:  171
Drew  475652 lines

Time taken:  251
Drew  318709 lines

Time taken:  5
Drew  14160 lines

Time taken:  16
Drew  27233 lines

The following code segment is used to time and count line segments drawn. Rendering happens to a off screen image (QImage with format Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied). The size of the QImage is at max 1366 x 768. segments type is QVector.

```
QTime m_timer;
m_timer.start();
painter.drawLines(segments);
qDebug() << "Time taken: " << m_timer.elapsed();
painter.end();
qDebug() << "Drew " << segments.size();
```

This QImage is cached to save future draws. I have never used DirectX. Will Direct 2D rendering give any more performance advantage than what I already have. Is there any way to improve on these numbers?

If Direct 2D rendering can improve these numbers what tech stack to use? Will using C#/SharpDX be better? I ask this because Qt can do DirectX through translation only (not sure what the cost is) and since the app is predominantly windows C# might ease the dev. process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be optimal to create your own line drawing function, operating on QImage memory buffer directly. There you can make some assumptions which Qt's painter probably can not do and achieve better performance. Then blit the image to screen antialiased (and possibly zoomed?) using QGLWidget.

Good line drawing code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Simplification .
Though for C++ and memory buffer implemenation, it can be further optimized by replacing `x0` and `y0` coordinates with single pointer.

Most importantly, you can then get line drawing inlined within you lines loop and have zero function calls while iterating over a million lines.

If you let the blitting part do antialiasing, you can just set a memory word per pixel without checking what kind of pen it is etc.

Also doing zooming in HW to any desired target resolution, you can freely optimize the QImage size for getting the pattern you want, separate from showing it on screen.

If you can have the lines mostly sorted by Y coordinate, that will help with caching, as setting pixels of sequential lines will be closer in memory in the QImage buffer.

However you do it, crank up optimization (-O3 flag for gcc, not sure of MS compiler), default is not max at least for gcc.

Another thing you can do is parallelize the drawing at per-image level, that will work even with QPainter. It is allowed to draw on QImage in other than main thread, and Qt makes it easy to just send QImages as signal parameter from drawing threads to GUI thread. What you do is heavily CPU and memory bound so better have drawing thread count same as real core count, not counting hyperthreading.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I never though of reimplementing line drawing. The code I have does not call draw line a million time. Creates all the million end points and puts it through in one call.

Comment: Ah right, then speed benefit will be less, but I think Qt code will have non-inlined function calls in it's library code... Doing simple line drawing should not be hard, so you might want to test it. Even without optimizing, it should give a an indication if you should optimize your own line drawing or if Qt implementation is equally fast. Also, as Qt is open source, you might check for example this: http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qpaintengine_raster.cpp.html#3142

Comment: About the zoom part. The app renders image segments at the current zoom level. Whenever the user zooms X or Y the visible scene is rendered and cached. If the user scrolls back and forth the cache solves the performance problem but when zoom changes cache is cleared. If I let the HW do scaling (zooming) on a fixed QImage size won't lines look thick when one zooms in?

Comment: Yeah, antialising can do only so much. What you could do is, when zooming back out you do not need to clear the cache. Also slight zooming in (1.5x maybe) could be ok without clearing the cache immediately, you could take advantage of this when user is zooming, to get smoother but slightly blocky zooming and get new image only when user stops zooming.

Comment: ...or, with multiple threads, when user starts to zoom in, you could start calculating a higher resolution image in another thread, while scaling the current image.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This can definitely help make the experience much more fluid.
I guess I have to see how implementing line drawing goes. I feel there might be something there.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know Qt, but for Direct2D, you wouldn't have good performance drawing millions of antialiased lines on Windows 7 (without latest IE10/SP update). On Windows 8, Direct2D has been slightly improved, but I'm not sure It can handle such a rate. If you want to achieve better performance, you would have to use directly Direct3D with a MSAA surface or possibly some screespace posteffect like FXAA, or using geometry aware anti-aliasing techniques like GPAA/GBAA. Check "[Filtering Approaches for Real-Time Anti-Aliasing](http://www.iryoku.com/aacourse/)" comprehensive list of state of the art real-time anti-aliasing techniques.

Comment: So are you suggesting something like this, where I create a D3D device and using a Texture2D as render target say like what is being discussed here http://sharpdx.org/forum/5-api-usage/567-wpf-and-direct2d ? Just that I am getting my feet wet with DX for the first time and I have no clue where to begin

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I won't answer your question directly, but:

- I guess, that Qt uses standard system routines to perform graphical operations, so it means GDI and/or GDI+ here. Neither of these if fast, both do all computations on CPU. On the other hand Direct2D from DirectX11+ attempts to accelerate drawings using GPU power if possible, so it *may* work faster.
- I don't know Qt well, but I guess, that you should be able to retreive a handle to window (=control) you want to draw on somehow (even if that means using WinAPI - there's always a way). If so, you can bypass all Qt mechanisms and draw directly on that window using DirectX with no additional overhead.
- As for SharpDX - I didn't know, that such library exists, thanks for info. They published a paper informing about performance of operation, you may want to check it out: http://code4k.blogspot.com/2011/03/benchmarking-cnet-direct3d-11-apis-vs.html . Anyway, it seems to be a more or less simple wrapper around DirectX headers, so it shouldn't add much overhead to your application (unless performance is *really* critical).

Comment: +1 for window handle point, that might be a very good solution too. Though if lines are on average short, and it's ok to do antialising for finished image instead of per-line (or not at all), then there's probably so much per-line overhead that speedup in actual drawing is negated.

Comment: Do you think so? Even with graphics card support?

Comment: I don't know the DX API and it's internal GPU interface, so I have no idea what kind of overhead per line segment there is, but I suspect the overhead is not irrelevant. A million lines is, at the minimum, 4MB of raw coordinate data (two coordinates per line at 16 bits), at worst case 32 MB (four coordinates per line at 64 bits). If it can be transferred as bulk raw bytes then it's not so bad, but if it's more complicated to transfer stuff like this to GPU, then it's a killer.